# Blog reading and following for busy people

Tags: rss, blog, rss-reader

There are lots of RSS readers out there, but they just flood you with a big list of all the posts from the site to date. For those of us who are time-starved, but still like to keep in touch in a passive way (meaning not regularly going through your RSS reader like your inbox), this is overwhelming.

What I want this reader to do is, whenever I have some time to catch up, show me the top X posts (using whatever criteria) from the blog for a specific time period. This period could be a day, a week or a month! By this way, even if I took a long break, I could still catch up and feel not being left out!

Are there any apps like this out there?

Comment: I'd sign up and pay for this app! Best to look at community-driven news by subjects since community will promote the most interesting stories.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at Google Readers 'sort by magic' feature;

http://www.gtricks.com/google-reader-tricks/what-is-sort-by-magic-in-google-reader/

http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2009/10/reading-gets-personal-with-popular.html

> Only have a 10 minute coffee break and want to see the best items first? All feeds now have a new sort option called "magic" that re-orders items in the feed based on your personal usage, and overall activity in Reader, instead of default chronological order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that helps a little. Still, the presence of long list of unread posts daunts me. What I was hoping for was some reader that will show a digest. For example: for this blog, these are the most popular 10 posts for the last month.